# How to look at the data stored in a QMap?

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures

How to look at the data stored in QMap without iterating through it? I am trying to debug an application using QMap with many keys, do you know a way to look at the data in QMap without iterating through each value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will dump the content of a QMap (and other Qt types) to `stderr`:

```
qDebug() << yourQMap;
```

Comment: Also if you use Qt Creator, the debugger let you peek into most if not all Qt containers.